# What is the standard order to develop software features in?

Tags: software-design

For a beginner hobbyist, it seems fairly common to create everything in the order it will be viewed by the user, regardless of its importance, and to intertwine back-end and front-end development.

Obviously, this isn't the most efficient method and would probably be avoided by more experienced developers. I've been exploring different ways to order software development, but I'd like to know if there's a standard that's widely accepted or recommended by the industry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is what [software development processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_process) are for.

Thing is: there are many different processes; thus there are many different answers to your question.

In 2017, most organisations use processes around the "agile" mindset (or they try to get there), thus your first stop could be [Agile software development](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agile_software_development).

And to give a direct answer to your question:

- when you start an agile project, you simply don't know about "all the things the user will view"
- instead, you collect requirements
- you translate requirements into "user stories"
- then the development team and the users (or user representatives) decide on the **priority** of those user stories
- and then, during the development iterations (sprints) a subset of the "most important" user stories is implemented

The **key** part here: requirements and their priorities are subject to **change**. The idea to collect *everything* upfront, to then define an order over **all items** is simply rejected nowadays.